# Angular Parse GET Return

Tags: angularjs

`m` gets generated in a factory with the following request:

```
  var m = $http({method: 'GET', url: JSONurl});
```

Console log of `m` after the GET request:

[image: console log of m]

I need to grab `m`'s "data:" which has the `Array[2]` I need. How would I create a new variable with just the data array?

Comment: `m.then(res => res.data)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the angularJS [docs for $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http), you'll see that you'll need to use the promise to get the data. So you want something along the lines of:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: JSONurl
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    //response has the data on a successful call
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    //this response will have the error data on a failed call
  });
```